# How do I check database for a value that already exists?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently building a signup script for my website. I new to the whole PHP-mySQL interaction bit. Anyway, this is the code I've gotten so far. The problem is that I had added some more code to check if the username already exists in the database, after the form submits it kicks to store.viddir.com/join/signup.php rather than store.viddir.com/login, like I had it. Any pros that can help a novice out? Many thanks

```
<?php
      $submitted = $_POST["submitted"];
      if($submitted == 'yes') {

      $firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
      $lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
      $userName = $_POST["userName"];
      $password = $_POST["password"];
      $confirmPassword = $_POST["confirmPassword"];
      $eMail = $_POST["eMail"];

      // Kill script if input fields are blank
      if ($firstName == '' or $lastName == '' or $userName == '' or $password == '' or $confirmPassword == '' or $eMail == '')
      {
        die();
      }

      // Check if passwords match
      if ($password != $confirmPassword)
      {
        die();
      }

      // Check if password is appropriat length
      $passwordLength = strlen($password);
      if ($passwordLength < 7 or $passwordLength >30) {
        die();
      }

      /////////////////////////
      // Connect to database //
      /////////////////////////

      $sqlserver = "localhost";
      $sqluser = "XXXX";
      $sqlpassword = "XXXXXX";

      mysql_connect($sqlserver, $sqluser, $sqlpassword) or die(mysql_error());

      mysql_select_db("store");

      // Check database if username already exists  
      $newUserName = $userName;
      $checkUserName = mysql_query("SELECT userName FROM userInfo WHERE userName = '$newUserName'");
      if ($checkUserName) {
        die();
        }

      //////////////////////////
      // Insert into database //
      //////////////////////////

      // Signup time in Unix Epoch
      $time = time();

      // Human readable date
      $date = date("F jS, Y  g:i:s A");

      $sql = "INSERT into userInfo (firstName, lastName, userName, password, eMail, time, date) VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$userName', '$password', '$eMail', '$time', '$date')";
        //$sqlserver = "localhost";
        //$sqluser = "XXXX";
        //$sqlpassword = "XXXXXX";


        //mysql_connect($sqlserver, $sqluser, $sqlpassword) or die(mysql_error());

        //mysql_select_db("store");

      mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

      mysql_close();

      header("Location: http://store.viddir.com/login");
      exit;
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you to use the \PDO object instead of mysql_connect(). It will help you to get a better code architecture and make your program more scalable and easier to maintain. Take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

See mysql_num_rows. You should also look into using PDO or MySQLi

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    echo "user already exists";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do a count in the mysql query and then check if the result is not equal to 0.

Example:

```
// Check database if username already exists  
  $newUserName = $userName;
  $checkUserName = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(userName) FROM userInfo WHERE userName = '$newUserName'");
  if ( mysql_result($checkUserName, 0, 0) != 0 ) {
    die();
    }
```